# Should I use NoSQL or Relational DB on an API

Tags: json, nosql, relational-database

I'm building an API and I need to store some data, I'm using JSON as my response format instead of XML but I really dont know how to store my data, for example I have this

```
 {users: [
  user: "name",
  products: [Array with more than 100 products],
  etc: "other items"], etc...
 }
```

the problem is that inside the user i have many arrays so maybe it may affect my db performance so I dont know if to choose NoSQL or Relational DB.
So my question really is, does having too many nested arrays with many items inside an object affect my db performance? or should i choose another method for saving my data

Comment: This seems like it may be right in MongoDB's wheelhouse.

Comment: even if i have many nested items inside "products"? for example
[{id: "", name: "", description: "", price: ""}, etc..]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using NoSQL db then storing data in multiple rows (or normalization) effectively ignores one of the best purposes of NoSQL.. storing it all together will make your software faster as there will be less IO.

In my project I am storing the entire user data and properties (that 3rd party apps can set via OAuth) in a single document. MongoDB has a document size limit of 16MB and it's just a soft limit.

In this situation you can determine which fields are common to all (id, name, etc), then set a maximum size for these common fields (say name will be 128 chars). MongoDB strings are UTF-8. You can now determine that these static fields will take up X bytes of every document. The remaining 16MB - X bytes are there in every document for your allocation to arrays and custom properties, etc.

Set a max size M to these values and, thus you can set a cap value N=(16MB - X bytes)/M 
that will effectively prevent your document data from overflowing the limit.

Comment: one thing that I forgot to mention: the field names themselves take up space in the document so please account for those as well. Thus, it is advisable to keep the field names as small as possible. I often use field names like a,b,c,1,2,etc, but it makes shell operation difficult.